# How to add specular map,bump map and colour texture in one object using x3d?

Tags: x3d

I want to find a way to add specular map and bump map on a object,but after I read the documantation of vrml97 and x3d ,I can not find any method.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to add color/light to an object you can use `Appearance` node:

```
Appearance { 
  exposedField SFNode material          NULL
  exposedField SFNode texture           NULL
  exposedField SFNode textureTransform  NULL
}
```

The `material` field can be a `Material` node:

```
Material { 
  exposedField SFFloat ambientIntensity  0.2         # [0,1]
  exposedField SFColor diffuseColor      0.8 0.8 0.8 # [0,1]
  exposedField SFColor emissiveColor     0 0 0       # [0,1]
  exposedField SFFloat shininess         0.2         # [0,1]
  exposedField SFColor specularColor     0 0 0       # [0,1]
  exposedField SFFloat transparency      0           # [0,1]
}
```

Or, if you want to add texture to your object you can use `texture` or `textureTransform` fields.

You can find all you need on [web3d.org](http://www.web3d.org/x3d/specifications/vrml/ISO-IEC-14772-VRML97/part1/nodesRef.html).